# Quel point Pronom

Tags: grammaire

*il sait à quel point j’aime* translates to "he knows how much I love"

The full sentence is *car il sait à quel point j’aime à résoudre les problèmes* and I've played around with the sentence to see at what point *quel point* becomes **how much**.

When would I use *quel point* to mean **how much**?  What grammatical categories does this fall under?

Comment: As Simon Déchamps already stated, *à quel point* translates to "to what extent*. That's even a word by word translation. Here *point* = *degré/niveau/limite* = extent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's ***à quel point*** that means *how much*, not just *quel point*. In some cases it can be translated into *to what extent*, in others it's more *how*, sometimes why not *to what degree*. All of them have close meanings, even if not always interchangeable.

You can almost always replace it by *combien*, which literally means *how much*:

> Tu sais combien j'adore cette musique !

Oh and I can't think of a case with *at what point* meaning *à quel point*, so I suppose we can say they are false friends.

And it's an adverb.